# Warning: The tag <lable> is unrecognized in this browser

Tags: reactjs, label

How to rectify it? everything seems okay, spelling/syntax etc.. still getting this warning in console.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oJlmd.png)

just using this label tag in react environment.

Comment: Maybe  you want <label>

Comment: Or perhaps `<table>`?

Comment: can you please add the warning and bit more info?

Comment: react-dom.development.js:86 Warning: The tag <lable> is unrecognized in this browser. If you meant to render a React component, start its name with an uppercase letter.
    at lable
    at div
    at LogIn (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:667:76)
    at RenderedRoute (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:46996:5)
    at Routes (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:47461:5)
    at MainRoutes
    at div
    at App
    at EnvironmentProvider (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:60237:5)

Answer (score 0):

You misspelled, it should be **label**.

It will work, thanks.

```
  <label for="html">HTML</label><br>
```

[Ref-W3school](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_label.asp)